# how to integrate this equation with two sums inside?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I'm reading a book, and I have trouble with this problem. I don't know how to integrate this equation and where to begin from. Although they already give the answer but I don't understand how to get it. I need help from you, Thanks in advance!

This is equation to calculate the bending strain energy of a plate.
![pic of problem] (https://s28.postimg.org/f0e29kxql/inte1.jpg)

Comment: i am sure that you have to use the orthogonality properties of the trigonometric functions. So my plan would be: 1.) write out the product, 2.) 3.) look up the relations mentioned above, 4.) calculate 5.) kill some of the sums using the kronecker deltas which will appear

Comment: I got what you said,thank you. But can I have on more question, why in the answer there appear the letter "r" and "s" beside "m" "n" in the answer? Where do they come from? I'm really bad at series.

Comment: Bad link.  Without the link the problem is worthless.  So why bother correcting the grammar and bumping the question to the front page?